# Could -[NSURL URLByResolvingSymlinksInPath] return nil?

Tags: objective-c

I'am analysing some crash reports from users of my OS X app. From the call stack it looks like  the NSURL API I used in my code:

```
-[NSURL URLByResolvingSymlinksInPath]
```

returned nil. I thought the API never returns nil so I passed the return url value to another method without nil check, which crashes the application.

So, am I wrong? Is that possible that the API returns nil?

[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/URLByResolvingSymlinksInPath) says the api will return broken symbolic links if some symbolic links cannot be resolved. And I tried many ways(circular symblink, symlink that points nothing...) to make the API return nil but no success.

Comment: How do you create your NSURL? If I do `NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:nil]; NSLog(@"%@", [url URLByResolvingSymlinksInPath]);` it prints `(null)`. So if you do the same your string might be nil.

Comment: [NSURL URLWithString:nil] returns nil, so you were sending URLByResolvingSymlinksInPath to nil. In my code the url is from iterating directory using NSFileManager, so the url is not nil.